# android app for parental control to read all http requests

Tags: android

I am new to android and looking at developing an app(background service) for parental control. What the app accomplishes is, it looks at the domain name of the request from browser or any app and if it the domain is within the banned list, it will send a notification to the parent's app that the kid is visiting a banned website (majorly focused on porn, but parents can choose to add any domain to banned list).

I know that if the kid is clever enough to use a proxy, then the whole purpose is defeated. We have a chrome extension doing the same, how do I get the http request of all browsers and apps directed to my app, before forwarding it further? What are the permissions needed in my manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't provide a central point where you can inspect all http traffic from all apps.

Unless you root the device, your only option is to write your app to pretend to be a VPN.

This is the approach used by various no-root firewalls, and traffic shaping apps such as Opera Max.  However it's not really going to work for parental controls - Android requires that the user explicitly agrees to the VPN being created, so the child could easily say no, and thus run without the controls in place.

Comment: Does it ask for permission every time or only during installation ?

Comment: Every time the app is run

Comment: can you guide me to an example of this approach, so I can try and see myself

Comment: after going over everything, i feel vpn is the only choice i am left with. can you please point me to a development source guide or blog post which would be helpful to get started with VPN approach